# How to stop code from calculating twice

Tags: c++

My code is suppose to calculate 5% on to a salary and 10% on a salary. When compiled the outcome is the 5% calculating right but I think the 10% is adding the 5% on top of the 10%. How would I fix this?

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fivePercentRaise(double &);

void tenPercentRaise(double &);

int main()

{

double salary = 0.0;
cout << "Please enter current salary: ";

cin >> salary;

fivePercentRaise(salary);

tenPercentRaise(salary);

system("pause");

return 0;

}

void fivePercentRaise(double & sal)

{

sal = sal * 0.05 + sal;

cout << "New salary if you receive a 5% raise: " << sal << endl;

}

void tenPercentRaise(double & sal)

{

sal =  sal * 0.10 + sal;

cout << "New salary if you receive a 10% raise: " << sal << endl;

}
```

Comment: please use a debugger and close this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is easily solved with a debugger.

Comment: @djechlin the question is "How would I fix this?", which a debugger does not help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're telling your functions ('fivePercentRaise()','tenPercentRaise()') to take the input variable, salary, by reference instead of by value. When you tell the functions to take the variable by reference,'fivePercentRaise()' will raise the value stored in the value 'salary' by 5%. Then you pass that same variable to 'tenPercentRaise()' who gladly raises the same 'salary' variable by 10%.

Get rid of the ampersands in your pre-processor directives and function definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is:

```
fivePercentRaise(salary);
tenPercentRaise(salary);
```

These functions work by taking `salary` by reference, and modifying it in-place. So you are indeed calculating a 5% raise and then calculating a 10% raise on top of that (compounded).

You have a few options:

- Save the value of `salary` before calling `fivePercentRaise` and then restore it
- Take the argument by value, and return the updated value
- Take the argument by value, not returning anything since you do not use the value outside the function anyway

A more normal design would be for your function to perform the raise, and then the calling code does the output.  Then you do not need to modify the function if you want to apply the 5% raise in another scenario where you don't want to also print out what happened.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving two raises sequentially.

Assume 100 dollar salary:

5 percent raise:  105

10 percent raise (of 105) : 115.50

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is the function declaration:

```
void tenPercentRaise(double & sal)
```

When you use a reference, with `&`, you will modify the variable that was used to call the function.

Please read about "pass by reference" and "pass by value."  Understanding that distinction, it should be straightforward to fix the functions.